# Only running Pygame display code once data revieved from python socket connection

Tags: python, pygame, python-sockets

I want to write a pygame programme where I am receiving data from a Raspberry Pi over a socket connection. However I only want the Pygame code to run once the string has arrived. This involves the code waiting for some time, then when a string is received from the Raspberry Pi, pygame runs code to update the display.
Currently my Pygame freezes and shuts down when waiting for data to income. 
Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add some code of 'waiting' and creation of socket?

Answer (score 0):

Pygame "freezes" is most likely due to the network call being blocking. Consider spinning a new thread to handle the data communication while Pygame takes over the main thread and updates the display with some "waiting" message. Once you have received the data, the second thread should pass it to the main thread which will display it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues at play here.  As @Josep Valls answers, the code needs to do the socket communications in a sub-thread.  Additionally, the PyGame main thread needs to continually poll the event loop (and possibly repaint the screen).  Obviously if the code is not doing anything much on each loop, maybe it's not necessary to re-paint the entire screen every time like in the example below.

So, what's needed to handle the socket communications with PyGame? First you need to be listening on a socket to accept connections.  In the example, the `ConnectionHandlerThread` class does exactly this.  It listens for incoming client connections, and when once occurs, it creates a `ConversationHandlerThread` to do the reading/writing for each client.  (If you're doing a lot of sockets coming and going, maybe you'd want a thread pool for this, but I'm also trying to keep the example simple.)

So to explain the example code - it paints a window with a couple of `AlienSprite` bouncing around.  Clients can connect to it on port `5555` (say with `telnet`) and issue commands.  Sending a colour word (red/green/blue) spawns a new alien in that colour.  The `quit` command disconnects.

To communicate between the socket-handling threads and the PyGame main thread, the socket-threads use PyGame `event.post()` to send events.  These user-events have been implemented in an `enum` named `NetworkEvents` to keep track of them.  The beauty of this is you're not confused when two threads are both posting `pygame.USEREVENT + 27` for different event types.

```
import threading
import pygame
import random
import enum
import socket
import select

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH=400
WINDOW_HEIGHT=400

DARK    = (  50, 50, 50 )
WHITE   = ( 255,255,255 )
RED     = ( 255, 55, 55 )
GREEN   = (   5,255, 55 )
BLUE    = (   5, 55,255 )

LISTEN_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'
LISTEN_PORT    = 5555


class NetworkEvents( enum.IntEnum ):
    CLIENT_CONNECTED = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    CLIENT_HANGUP    = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
    CLIENT_MESSAGE   = pygame.USEREVENT + 3


class AlienSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    """ A tiny little alien, which wanders around the screen """
    def __init__( self, colour ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = self.render( colour )
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH ), random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )

    def render( self, colour ):
        new_image = pygame.Surface( ( 7, 6 ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
        new_image.fill( (0,0,0,0) )
        pixels = [                     (3,1),               \
                                (2,2), (3,2), (4,2),        \
                            (1,3),     (3,3),      (5,3),   \
                                (2,4), (3,4), (4,4) ]
        for p in pixels:
            new_image.set_at( p, colour )
        return new_image

    def update( self ):
        self.rect.x += random.randrange( -2, 3 )
        self.rect.y += random.randrange( -2, 3 )
        # remove if we wander off-screen
        if ( self.rect.x < 0 or self.rect.x >= WINDOW_WIDTH or \
             self.rect.y < 0 or self.rect.x >= WINDOW_HEIGHT ):
            self.kill() 




class ConversationHandlerThread( threading.Thread ):
    """ A thread that handles a conversation with a single remote client.
        Accepts commands of 'red', 'green' or 'blue', and posts messages
        to the main PyGame thread for processing """
    def __init__( self, client_socket, client_address ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client_socket  = client_socket
        self.client_address = client_address
        self.data_buffer    = ''
        self.daemon         = True # exit with parent
        self.done           = False

    def stop( self ):
        self.done = True

    def run( self ):
        """ Loops until the client hangs-up """
        read_events_on   = [ self.client_socket ]
        while ( not self.done ):
            # Wait for incoming data, or errors, or 0.3 seconds
            (read_list, write_list, except_list) = select.select( read_events_on, [], [], 0.5 )

            if ( len( read_list ) > 0 ):
                # New data arrived, read it
                incoming = self.client_socket.recv( 8192 )
                if ( len(incoming) == 0):
                    # Socket has closed
                    new_event = pygame.event.Event( NetworkEvents.CLIENT_HANGUP, { "address" : self.client_address } )
                    pygame.event.post( new_event )
                    self.client_socket.close()
                    self.done = True
                else:
                    # Data has arrived
                    try:
                        new_str = incoming.decode('utf-8')
                        self.data_buffer += new_str
                    except: 
                        pass # don't understand buffer

                    # Parse incoming message (trivial parser, not high quality) 
                    # commands are '\n' separated
                    if (self.data_buffer.find('\n') != -1 ):
                        for line in self.data_buffer.split('\n'):
                            line = line.strip()
                            # client disconnect command
                            if ( line == 'close' ):
                                new_event = pygame.event.Event( NetworkEvents.CLIENT_HANGUP, { "address" : self.client_address } )
                                pygame.event.post( new_event )
                                self.client_socket.close()
                                self.done = True

                            # only make events for valid commands
                            elif ( line in ( 'red', 'green', 'blue' ) ):
                                new_event = pygame.event.Event( NetworkEvents.CLIENT_MESSAGE, { "address" : self.client_address, "message" : line  } )
                                pygame.event.post( new_event )
                        self.data_buffer = ''  # all used-up






class ConnectionHandlerThread( threading.Thread ):
    """ Opens a socket, listening for incoming connections.
        If a client connects, notifies the PyGame main thread with a message,
        and starts a conversation handler thread to accept commands """
    def __init__( self ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True # exit with parent
        self.done   = False

    def stop( self ):
        self.done = True

    def run( self ):
        # Establish a socket-listener
        rx_sock = socket.socket() 
        rx_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        rx_sock.bind( ( LISTEN_ADDRESS, LISTEN_PORT ) )
        while ( not self.done ):
            rx_sock.listen( 3 ) # small queue
            client_socket, remote_addr = rx_sock.accept()
            print("Connection from %s" % ( str( remote_addr ) ) )
            # Tell the main thread someone connected via an event
            new_event_args = { "socket"  : client_socket, "address" : remote_addr  }
            new_event = pygame.event.Event( NetworkEvents.CLIENT_CONNECTED, new_event_args )
            pygame.event.post( new_event )
            # Start a thread to handle the socket-conversation with the client
            new_thread = ConversationHandlerThread( client_socket, remote_addr )
            new_thread.start()




###
### MAIN
###

# Create the window
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Socket Messages")
WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE )

# Create some sprites
SPRITES = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range( 3 ):
    new_sprite = AlienSprite( WHITE )
    SPRITES.add( new_sprite )

# Start the connection-listener thread
thread1 = ConnectionHandlerThread()
thread1.start()

# Main paint / update / event loop
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while ( not done ):
    SPRITES.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

        elif ( event.type == NetworkEvents.CLIENT_HANGUP ):
            print(" CLIENT DISCONNECTED %s " % ( str(event.address) ) )

        elif ( event.type == NetworkEvents.CLIENT_CONNECTED ):
            print(" NEW CLIENT FROM %s " % ( str(event.address) ) )

        elif ( event.type == NetworkEvents.CLIENT_MESSAGE ):
            print(" CLIENT MESSAGE FROM %s - %s " % ( str(event.address), event.message ) )
            if ( event.message == 'red' ):
                new_sprite = AlienSprite( RED )
                SPRITES.add( new_sprite )
            elif ( event.message == 'blue' ):
                new_sprite = AlienSprite( BLUE )
                SPRITES.add( new_sprite )
            elif ( event.message == 'green' ):
                new_sprite = AlienSprite( GREEN )
                SPRITES.add( new_sprite )

        elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
            WINDOW_WIDTH  = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE )

    WINDOW.fill( DARK )
    SPRITES.draw( WINDOW )
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

thread1.stop()
pygame.quit()
```

My apologies for the length of code in this answer, but I feel it's necessary to correctly demonstrate an appropriate answer.  Leaving out the enumerated type, or perhaps the socket listener would hinder the learning value.